# What do Brits means when they say "perving around"?

Tags: british-english

A friend mentioned her British girlfriend talking about drinking and "perving around the pool." What are the possible meanings for this? I gather from my friend's story that this Brit wasn't a pervert, as the word might imply, but was it an ironic usage? Anyone from the U.K. want to chime in?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not *perving around*, just *perving*, but it's an activity that, like drinking, might well take place around a pool.

It is related to *pervert*, but used in a self-deprecating way - your friend just means *enjoying the sight of attractive bodies on display*. A synonym would be *leching* (from "lechery", again a self-deprecating use of a term with stronger connotations).

Comment: Another synonym would be "oogling".

Comment: @Peter - I think you mean "**[ogling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ogling)**"?

Comment: @MT_Head: You're right, that is the standard English word. But I've heard "oogling" (and indeed "oggling") plenty of times in the UK too :)

Comment: I don't usually make spelling corrections; I just wanted to clarify that it's a "real" word, rather than a slang term (if you Google "oogle", you get sent to Urban Dictionary - ewww.)  Interestingly, the derivation of "ogle" seems to be from... "oog".  Go figure.

Comment: @MT_Head: Sure... and *ogle->oogling* matches the theme of *pervert->perving* and *lecher->leching* i.e. forming slang words for this meaning from modifications of "real" ones :)

Answer (score 4):

There's an exact old word equivalent to "perving" which is still in use in the East Midlands. When someone is peeping slyly, he is said to be "chiking",and is called a "chiker".

That is a long "i" sound, and the word is probably better represented "ch-eye-ker" for pronunciation. The spelling I give is from printed usage I have seen. There is a short story by Alan Sillitoe, titled "The Chiker".

Answer (score 1):

If she is from Liverpool then it basically means a night out in Liverpool; if I extend it from drinking (obvious) to perving (looking for a S one H night A stand G) in 'the pool' (that's how Scouses refer to Liverpool) or just having a drink and perving (looking for 
C a L suitable U partner N to G love E) around a swimming pool.